# Warning: Type is restricted by a facet pattern that may impede a full round-tripping of instances of this type

Tags: xml, xsd, ssms, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I always get these warnings for both my `xsd:dateTime` validation.

```
+'              <xsd:element name="ProductCreationDate" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">'
+'                  <xsd:simpleType>'
+'                      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:dateTime">'
+'                          <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" fixed="true"/>'
+'                          <xsd:pattern value="\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"/>'
+'                      </xsd:restriction>'
+'                  </xsd:simpleType>'
+'              </xsd:element>'
```

And this warning displays on the Messages pane:

> Warning: Type `xs-nun(/ProductCreationDate/simpleType())` is restricted by a facet `pattern` that may impede a full round-tripping of instances of this type

Anyone knows how to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, this is nothing more than SQL Server telling you to make sure that the pattern matches the data type. It is possible to add a pattern that matches no valid dateTime string, so that the resulting type can never pass validation (either failing base type or pattern restriction).

If your pattern is OK it is safe to ignore the warning, but I do not know of any way to suppress the message.

Answer (score 0):

The tool, which you've not specified, is telling you that it may not be capable of round-tripping through this constraint.  Remove the `pattern` (or really the entire `restriction`), if you want to remove the warning, or ignore it if you don't care about round-tripping.

Note that such round-tripping concerns are not usually reported by validating parsers.  Perhaps you're using a tool that does mapping to object oriented classes (e.g. JAXB or xsd.exe) where a simple validating XML parser would suffice.

Comment: The tool used is SSMS directly. I need to validate an XML document from a column prior to put the doc's content into a proper table.

Comment: Now that you've added an [tag:ssms] tag, perhaps someone with experience with SSMS can provide further help.  As I mentioned in this answer, the warning is more about that tool than it is about *standard* XML or XSD.  Use a standard validating XML parser if you'd like to validate against the standards without regard to the idiosyncrasies of SSMS.